# Generate coverage for other modules

Tags: gradle, code-coverage, android-espresso, jacoco

My project structure is as follows: `:app`, `:core`. `:app` is the Android application project, and it depends on `:core` which has all the business logic.

I have `Espresso` tests for `:app`, and I am able to run and get coverage report thanks to all the questions and guides out there. But the coverage is only for code in `:app`.

How do I get coverage for all projects (`:app` and `:core`) resulting from my `Espresso` instrumentation tests? Is this even possible?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Even if you did not mention Jacoco in your question, it is listed in the tags, so I assume you want to create coverage reports by using it. The Gradle Jacoco plugin (`apply plugin: 'jacoco'`) allows you to create custom tasks of the type `JacocoReport`.

Defining such a task, you can specify source and class directories as well as the execution data:

```
task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport) {
    dependsOn // all your test tasks
    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = true
    }
    sourceDirectories = // files() or fileTree() to your source files
    classDirectories = // files() or fileTree() to your class files
    executionData = // files() or fileTree() including all your test results
}
```

For Espresso tests, the execution data should include all generated `.ec` files. You could define this task in the Gradle root project and link to both the files and the tasks of your subprojects.

There is [an example](https://medium.com/@rafael_toledo/setting-up-an-unified-coverage-report-in-android-with-jacoco-robolectric-and-espresso-ffe239aaf3fa) for a custom Jacoco report task, even if it aims on creating an unified report for multiple test types, it can be transfered for this multi-project problem.

Answer (score 1):

By default the `JacocoReport` task only reports coverage on sources within the project. You'll need to set the [additionalSourceDirs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.testing.jacoco.tasks.JacocoReport.html#org.gradle.testing.jacoco.tasks.JacocoReport:additionalSourceDirs) property on the `JacocoReport` task.

`app/build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

// tell gradle that :core must be evaluated before :app (so the sourceSets are configured)
evaluationDependsOn(':core') 

jacocoTestReport {
    def coreSourceSet = project(':core').sourceSets.main
    additionalSourceDirs.from coreSourceSet.allJava
    additionalClassDirs.from coreSourceSet.output
}
```